# how to fit collection view cell in table view cell ( adaptive on all screen sizes?)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-autolayout

My collection view cells (7 cells) need to fit into table view cell, but when I run it it shows differently in iPhone 6  and iPhone X .
Is there any way that I can overcome the issue?

[image]
Let's say I have 2 collection views which should cover and fit adaptively on different device screen sizes.

Comment: Can you post photos of the layout on the 2 different phones and a photo of your ideal layout?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom UITableViewCell

```
 override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
    self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    return self.collectionView.contentSize
}
```

and when u are configuring the cell means u are passing data From controller to your UITableViewCell use this in that

```
self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: is there any alternative way to use this with static table view without UItableViewCell instance?